# Working R script code not working in Markdown - RStudio hangs

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Can someone help me understand how valid r script code causes markdown document in rStudio to hang and become unresponsive to the point I have to terminate the session and the IDE? No document is knitted either

**Background:**

- Tried on 2 different machines, running latest rStudio Version
  0.99.489 and R 3.2.2 (64Bit) on Windows 7 & Windows 10.
- Tried using packrat to manage the packages
- Tried loading the shape file from within the project directory
- Tried loading a different shape file from spdep project download
- Tried reinstalling the packages again

**R Script**
Get the required libraries and load them

```
#Install the GIS packages
install.packages("spdep",dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("maptools",dependencies = TRUE)
#Load the libraries
library(spdep)
library(maptools)
```

This works in R (you will need to get the right location for the shape file on your system)

```
#See where the library files are stored
.libPaths() 
#Load the Eire shape file which came in spdep package using the readShapePoly function from maptools (needed to change the slashes from windows to those supported in R)
eireMap <- readShapePoly("C:R/3.2/spdep/etc/shapes/eire.shp"[1],ID="names", proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=30 +units=km"))
#Plot the map as there was no problem reading the shape file correctly in R script
plot(eireMap)
```

**R Markdown**

````
---
title: "GIS using R"
author: "Me"
date: "18 November 2015"
output: word_document
---

This is an R Markdown document of the R worksheet for GIS. Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code contained in that snippet

```{r, echo=FALSE}
#Install the packages if not done already
install.packages("spdep",dependencies = TRUE)
install.packages("maptools",dependencies = TRUE)
```

Load the libraries 
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(spdep)
library(maptools)
```


See where the library files are stored
```{r}
.libPaths() 
```

Try to Load the Eire shape file but it causes R Studio to hang and become unresponsive 
```{r}
eireMap <- readShapePoly("C:R/win-  library/3.2/spdep/etc/shapes/eire.shp"[1],ID="names", proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=30 +units=km"))
```

Can't plot the map because the system has hung by this stage
```{r}
plot(eireMap)
names(eireMap)
eireMap $names
```
````

Comment: The lines of code for creating 'eireMap' seem different, is that intentional?

Comment: FWIW `system.file("etc/shapes/eire.shp", package="spdep")` is the proper way to get to that shapefile. Also, why are you force-reinstalling the packages every time you knit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will let you check for packages before re-installing (and not display any messages while loading them). Then it uses a cross-platform way of getting the filename for the shapefile you need and then reads & plots it. The individual R code lines (i.e. non-Rmd) work fine in an R console and in RStudio + the Rmd knits fine on my OS X system and linux systems. There are more elegant ways to do the package check/load but this will let you quickly check to see if there is a bigger problem on your system.

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
if (!require(spdep)) install.packages("spdep",dependencies=TRUE)
if (!require(maptools)) install.packages("maptools",dependencies=TRUE)
require(spdep)
require(maptools)
```

```{r}
eire_shp <- system.file("etc/shapes/eire.shp", package="spdep")

eireMap <- readShapePoly(eire_shp, ID="names", 
                         proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=30 +units=km"))
```

```{r}
plot(eireMap)
names(eireMap)
eireMap$names
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your way is alot cleaner but more importantly works in markdown